# Multi user password reset concurrency issue in NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Unable to reset password for multiple users. I am stuck while multiple users trying to reset the password

How I do capture the exact reset token sent to specific user in email as link? Lets say when two user are trying to reset the password, the `resetQueryParameter` will be overridden. How do I handle this?

**Get the token from query parameters when users clicks on the reset link in email:**

```
// global variable
var resetQueryParameters = '';

//CAPTURE TOKEN (QUERY PARAMS) FROM LINK
app.get('/resetQuery/', function (req, res) {

    //SET THE TOKEN TO VARIABLE
    resetQueryParameters = req.query.token;
    r.db('myDB').table('Reset_Password').filter(r.row('auth_key').eq(req.query.token)).
    run(myConnection, function (err, cursor) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        cursor.toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    res.redirect(redirectResetPage);
                } else {
                    res.redirect(redirectLoginPage);
                }
                return result;
                console.log("printing reset link from db.....", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**getting the token when user clicks on link and verify the signature:**

```
function resetPassword(req, res, next) {
    console.log('reset password called from external link.....');

    nJwt.verify(resetQueryParameters, secretKey, function (err, verifiedJwt) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('reset token not valid...', err);
        } else {
            var params = {
                'username': verifiedJwt.body.details,
                'newPassword': req.params.newPassword
            };

            getApiResponse(resetURL, params, function (res1) {
                console.log('sending reset params to server...', params);
                if (res1.error) {
                    console.log('Could not reset password......', res1.error);
                } else {
                    console.log('reset password success.....');
                    resetQueryParameters = '';
                    res.json(res1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the `req.query.token` to `resetPassword` method?

Comment: @Aruna `req.query.token` still be overridden that way

Comment: Check my answer below, you can use the same with other name like, req.query.resetToken etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to use global variables here and not for any scenario.

When you do the redirect, you should pass the `req.query.token` to the `redirectResetPage` as below,

```
if (result.length > 0) {
   res.redirect(redirectResetPage + '?token=' + req.query.token);
} else {
   res.redirect(redirectLoginPage);
}
```

and let the page pass the same token back to the `resetPassword` method and use it there from the `request.query` or `request.body` but not from the global variable.

```
function resetPassword(req, res, next) {
    console.log('reset password called from external link.....');

    nJwt.verify(req.query.token, secretKey, function (err, verifiedJwt) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('reset token not valid...', err);
        } else {
            var params = {
                'username': verifiedJwt.body.details,
                'newPassword': req.params.newPassword
            };

            getApiResponse(resetURL, params, function (res1) {
                console.log('sending reset params to server...', params);
                if (res1.error) {
                    console.log('Could not reset password......', res1.error);
                } else {
                    console.log('reset password success.....');
                    resetQueryParameters = '';
                    res.json(res1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

> Note: The best practise is, store this token in the database if
>   possible or store it in the cookie/jwt token.

Comment: I was just thinking about that `res.redirect(redirectResetPage + '?token=' + req.query.token);` but passing data in redirect possible? I have seen example using `req.flash('token')` to pass data in redirect. I will give it a try as you have mentioned and let you know thanks

Comment: The token itself is a jwt token that I am using and also saving it rethinkdb before sending it to user in email

Comment: You can try the redirect as above and in your html, you have to take it from the query string in client side and pass the same to `resetPassword` method

Comment: its passing the query string in redirect correctly but unable to get it back in client side. I am using riotjs on client side. I will post another question on this anyway. Thank you

Comment: Sure, post and give me the link, I will have s look

Comment: Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957431/unable-to-capture-query-string-in-riotjs